# Copying csv in batch file causes file to be corrupted

Tags: batch-file, apex-data-loader

I use the following command to copy a csv (with the date in the name) to a directory called "read":
copy "C:\Users\Brock\Documents\Dropbox\dir\test\file????????.csv" "C:\Users\Brock\Documents\Dropbox\dir\test\file\read\file.csv"

When it is copied over there is some sort of invalid character (looks sort of like "->") that is causing Salesforce DataLoader to be unable to read the file.

Why is my file being corrupted and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `/b` switch to the `copy` command?

Answer (score 0):

```
copy "C:\Users\Brock\Documents\Dropbox\dir\test\file.csv" "C:\Users\Brock\Documents\Dropbox\dir\test\file\read\file.csv" /a /v
```

Try This...

Comment: Adding the `/a` will force the copy to use ASCII mode, and the → character will be added just the same.

Answer (score 0):

The CMD environment is detecting that the file is an ASCII file and is adding the ASCII `EOF` character (→) [0x26d, 0x1Ah] to the end of the newly copied file.

If you add the `/b` switch to the copy command, it will copy the file using binary mode and won't add the ASCII `EOF` character to the end of the copied file.

```
copy /b "C:\Users\Brock\Documents\Dropbox\dir\test\file????????.csv" "C:\Users\Brock\Documents\Dropbox\dir\test\file\read\file.csv"
```